Downloading template error Installing pods failed?
For the past few months, I seem to be getting a "Downloading template error Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed." error message.
I'm running the "npx --yes react-native@latest init  --version "latest"" command taken from:
https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started
I'm on windows and I've updated to the latest version of node.
Cheers.
